# Display google groups mails into wordpress

Tags: wordpress, gmail

I want to display our `googlegroups` mails into my website. i created my theme into `wordpress` and i want to create a widget and add a functionality to show mails into it. do you have any idea about it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this plugin (I've never used it): https://wordpress.org/plugins/odynogooglegroups/